# How can I make Selenium/Python wait for the user to login before continuing to run?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to run a script in Selenium/Python that requires logins at different points before the rest of the script can run.  Is there any way for me to tell the script to pause and wait at the login screen for the user to manually enter a username and password (maybe something that waits for the page title to change before continuing the script).

This is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import unittest, time, re, getpass

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

someVariable = getpass.getpass("Press Enter after You are done logging in")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="profile_pic_welcome_688052538"]').click()
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [WebDriverWait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp). For example, this performs a google search and then waits for a certain element to be present before printing the result:

```
import contextlib
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
with contextlib.closing(webdriver.Firefox()) as driver:
    driver.get('http://www.google.com')
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10) # timeout after 10 seconds
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    inputElement.send_keys('python')
    inputElement.submit()
    results = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_class_name('g'))
    for result in results:
        print(result.text)
        print('-'*80)
```

`wait.until` will either return the result of the lambda function, or a `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException` if the lambda function continues to return a Falsey value after 10 seconds.

You can find a little more information on `WebDriverWait` in the [Selenium book](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/book/Selenium_Documentation.pdf).

Comment: I still can't figure out how to make this work on a login page.  For instance, let's use facebook as an example.  When loading facebook in Selenium, it requires users to log in.  I want it to open facebook, wait for the user to manually log in, and then continue running the script once it detects that the user has reached the next page.

Comment: Login manually to facebook. Then save the HTML after login. Look for some element on that page that can act as a signal that the page as loaded. Then devise a `driver.find_elements_by_*(...)` to find that element. Use that in the `wait.until(...)` command.

Comment: I edited my original question with the code I have so far.  I'm using it as a learning tool for myself to build a larger automation tool.  When using the wait.until function, I received the error:  "global name "wait" is not defined.

Comment: The error is saying that the variable `wait` has not been defined. Look for the line that begins with `wait = ...` in my post above. Copy that line to your code. Since it uses `ui`, you'll also need to copy the import statement, `import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui`.

Comment: Brilliant.  If putting the lambda inside another function (for example, find_text_in_page) accepting a search parameter, be sure to enclose the parameter with `'`.  That tripped me up.

Comment: In JS with Webdriver.io, submission automatically blocks until (or returns a promise fulfilled when) the browser has finished loading the response.  There has to be a better way than this.

Answer (score 6):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import getpass # < -- IMPORT THIS

def loginUser():
    # Open your browser, and point it to the login page
    someVariable = getpass.getpass("Press Enter after You are done logging in") #< THIS IS THE SECOND PART
    #Here is where you put the rest of the code you want to execute
```

THEN whenever you want to run the script, you type `loginUser()` and it does its thing

this works because `getpass.getpass()` works exactly like `input()`, except it doesnt show any characthers ( its for accepting passwords and notshowing it to everyone looking at the screen)

So what happens is your page loads up. then everything stops, Your user manually logs in, and then goes back to the python CLI and hits enter.

Comment: I tried this, but couldn't get it to work.  I have added the code I am using into the description of my problem.

Comment: the `import getpass` and  `getpass.getpass("press enter")` are the important parts, i used pseudo sorry, ill edit my answer to be more 'realistic'

Comment: It still isn't working.  I'm sure I'm making a small mistake somewhere.  I edited my original question with my code.

Comment: lol, i know what you are doing... you are trying to copy paste it into the interpreter. You need to set up your code into DEFINITIONS.... im willing to be it goes right to that next line and doesnt even act like it got a someVariable... THEN you need to run the DEFINITION... ill edit my answer better now