# After submitting form, how to wait for element to load before clicking on said element? (Selenium / Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium and coding in Python.

After I submit a Javascript form, the page proceeds to load dynamically for results. I am essentially waiting for an element (a specific button link) to appear / finish loading so I can click on it. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `WebDriverWait`, Documentation [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp),

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement")))
finally:
    ff.quit()
```

Also, take a look at a similiar question, [How can I make Selenium/Python wait for the user to login before continuing to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927354/how-can-i-make-selenium-python-wait-for-the-user-to-login-before-continuing-to-r)